# Sum Multiple Columns not all adjacent by criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm looking to find a formula and/or VBA to determine how to sum multiple columns that are not together by criteria.  To use an example, Column A contains the criteria (i.e., cities).  Columns B to Column infinity contains data which are values.  I would like to sum the amounts in columns C,E,J,L,M,Z,AB,AE based on the criteria in column A.  Lets say the criteria for this example is "Dallas".  There can be an infinite amount of rows.  I've tried using sum products, other types of array based formulas.  I do have VBA written (very complex) that includes this analysis but it takes about 20 minutes to execute.  I feel that this is the piece of my VBA that slows it up because of the large set of data.  If I can make this part more efficient then believe I can reduce my overall executions time.  Ideally I should be able to sum the values in any grouping/combination of columns.  Any thoughts or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.  I'm running out of brainstorming ideas.

Comment: @Jeeped.  I'm assuming you have an advanced skill set in this area therefore you should understand that all types of users post questions on this site that mostly are not even near your level nor understand the appropriate vocabulary when describing a problem.  You understood the meaning behind my "terrible description".  If you are going to help then help, otherwise be respectful.

Comment: I've removed my comment and I'm sorry that you took offence. My point was that you are asking programmers for help and programmers *require* specifics, not generalities and poetic hyperbole. Perhaps this link will help: [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how fast, but it is does not apply SUMPRODUCT and is not an array formula:

```
  =SUM(SUBTOTAL(109,Sheet1!C:C),SUBTOTAL(109,Sheet1!E:E),SUBTOTAL(109,Sheet1!J:J))
```

(fill in the other columns to suit following the same pattern). Requires `Sheet1` or whatever your source sheet is called to be filtered to select `Dallas`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Not exactly what I was looking for but it did spark an idea for me to modify a Function I created.  I will let you know what the results are.

Answer (score 0):

```
=sum("Sheet1!A10:A100").
```

Maybe this will work for your question. If not, post a question so that we can work on it in a better way.